# IIS URL Rewrite subfolder to another folder name

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a question, how I can achieve the following result by creating a URL-Rewrite Rule. On wwwroot, I have the folder wordpress/demo that is accessible on e.g. www.example.com/wordpress/demo. 
However, I want to make this page accessible under www.example.com/example using URL-Rewrite rules.

I already searched a lot, but unfortunately, I have not found a solution yet. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you don't have it already please install URL Rewrite IIS module:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

After you install it open your web.config file and inside `<system.webServer>` paste this code:

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ExampleToDemo">
                    <match url="^(.*)example" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="wordpress/demo" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

I'm not sure about your structure but this one should work. You can also test it with "Test pattern" feature in IIS Url rewrite module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This also worked out for me. I finally created a virtual folder with and inserted the physical path to the virtual folder. That also worked out for me.

Comment: Above scenario can fail if i want to redirect from example.com/folder-name to example.com/blog/folder-name. as it is only matching folder-name that can exist in more than one place in website

Answer (score 0):

For a more complex case when you pass api params as route variables:
If you are using IIS management panel select your domain, the click module "URL Rewrite".

> Add Rule -> Blank Rule
>
> Enter name for this rule
>
> Select Append query string

```
Pattern: ^directoryfrom/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)

Rewrite URL: newsubdir/{R:1}/{R:2}
```

> Result: example.com/directoryfrom/{R:1}/{R:2} -> example.com/newsubdir/{R:1}/{R:2}

You may guess about r1 and r2, theses are subfolders you might have passed they will be converted auto into variables.